# Regex javascript result different than expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex

```
 var reg = new RegExp('["\\>]{1}\\$([^"\\<\\> ]*)["\\<]{1}', 'g');
```

That I run on this string

```
'<span>$name</span><img src="$images[0].src"><img src="$images[1].src"><img src="$images[2].src">'
```

If I test it on sites like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3ic7s) it works properly but if I test it in FireFox

```js
var reg = new RegExp('["\\>]{1}\\$([^"\\<\\> ]*)["\\<]{1}', 'g');
var match = reg.exec('<span>$name</span><img src="$images[0].src"><img src="$images[1].src"><img src="$images[2].src">');
console.log(match);
```

It only matches `">$name<"`. How to have it catch all like on the site?

This is not a duplicate. i'm not working with query strings, beside it works online of the site.

Comment: Avoid using regex for HTML text.

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML text.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape `>` and `<`.

Comment: And you practically never need `{1}`.

Comment: Note that in the example you gave from RegExr, you have the `g` (global) flag turned on

Comment: @smac89 He has that flag here, too.

Comment: Why are you using `new RegExp` instead of a literal in `//`?

Comment: @Barmar makes no difference, just a preference...

Comment: Not a duplicate, not working with query strings. Also it works online on regexr which is using JS I believe

Comment: You should look at that link again, the problem you are facing lies in not using a while loop with `exec` to retrieve all the matches. It may not be an exact duplicate, but it points to the reason why your single call to `exec` is not finding all the matches

Comment: They're much easier to read in literal format, since you don't have to double all the backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Regexp.prototype.exec()` just returns the first occurrence of a match, you have to call it in a loop to get all the matches.

Simpler is to use `String.prototype.match()`, it returns an array of all the matches.

You only need to use `exec()` if you also need to get the capture groups.

```js
var reg = new RegExp('[">]\\$[^"<> ]*["<]', 'g');
var str = '<span>$name</span><img src="$images[0].src"><img src="$images[1].src"><img src="$images[2].src">';
var match = str.match(reg);
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 4):

The **[`.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)** method return only the first occurrence, if you want to return all occurences use **[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** :

```js
var reg = new RegExp('[>"]\\$([^"<> ]*)["<]', 'gm');
var my_string = '<span>$name</span><img src="$images[0].src"><img src="$images[1].src"><img src="$images[2].src">';
var match = my_string.match(reg);

console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should convert HTML text to DOM and parse it.

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<span>$name</span><img src="$images[0].src"><img src="$images[1].src"><img src="$images[2].src">';
var result = [];
result.push(div.querySelector('span').innerText);
var src = Array.from(div.querySelectorAll('img')).map(img => img.getAttribute('src'));
result = result.concat(src);
console.log(result);
```

You can use `string#match`.

```js
var reg = new RegExp('["\\>]{1}\\$([^"\\<\\> ]*)["\\<]{1}', 'g');
var match = '<span>$name</span><img src="$images[0].src"><img src="$images[1].src"><img src="$images[2].src">'.match(reg);
console.log(match);
```